# TextBox not calculating the right way

Tags: c#, textbox, calculator

I have a Windows for application linked to a db. It should calculate some values from textBoxes when the text of this textBoxes changes. I wrote, it works fine, all of them, except one. If the text in the textBox2 is under 20, it calculates right, if it's above, it's not calculating correctly anymore, and I can even have any idea why is that. It's been 2 days so far since I have been trying to solve it, but nothing. Can anyone get it?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int total = textBox1.Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            textBox2.Text = total.ToString();
            textBox7.Text = (total * 8).ToString();
        }

        private void textBox7_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ore_l = textBox7.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
            int ore_n = textBox8.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
            int t = ((ore_l - ore_n) / 8);
            textBox2.Text = t.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox8_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //it is correct
            int ore_l = textBox7.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
            int ore_n = textBox8.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
            int t = ((ore_l - ore_n) / 8);
            textBox2.Text = t.ToString();

            //it isn't correct anymore
            int ac = label14.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(label14.Text);
            int zi_l = textBox1.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int zi_luc = textBox2.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int total = ac / zi_l * zi_luc;
            textBox6.Text = total.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox6_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int s = textBox4.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            int ac = label14.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(label14.Text);
            textBox5.Text = (ac + s).ToString();
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int b = label21.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(label21.Text);
            int sa = textBox1.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int t = (b / sa + (75 / 100 * b / sa));
            textBox10.Text = t.ToString();


            int s = textBox4.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            int ac = label14.Text == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(label14.Text);
            textBox5.Text = (ac + s).ToString();
        }
```

Test it with this values: ac = 1400 ; zi_l = 23 ; zi_luc = 23. So: 1400/23*23. It should be 1400 exactly, because it's int, and actually it is showing 1380.

P.S: It is not happening because of the text changing and gets the value wrong. I tried separately with a button, and method onClick, and it's the same result. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you divide 1400 by 23 you get 60.8xxxxxxxxxxx.

Because 1400 is an integer, the figures after the decimal point are chopped off. The calculation is then 60 * 23 = 1380.

If you want a better calculation, you'll need to use a float and then use `Math.Round` with `MidPointRoundingAwayFromZero`.

Comment: You're damn precisely right. Got me 2 days. So stupid of me not to think at this. Omg. Hahah. Thanks a lot !